# How to render and iterate through JSON with handlebars

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I have JSON file called twitData.json that looks like this:
[image: JSON file]

I want to iterate over it using Handlebars and Express, and pass it to a partial to be implemented as html code. I have included the JSON file in server.js. I use res.render in server.js to try and pass the elements of JSON to the partial. Like this: res.render('twitPage', {twitData}) . and for my handlebars file I use

`{{each .}}`
 `{{twit}}`
`{{/each}}`
The partial I am using, twit.handlebars, looks like this. It needs two arguments. I am supposed to pass the arguments somehow using res.render.

[image]

The main parts I do not understand is what to put as the second argument in res.render, and what I should put for the context in the {{each}} helper. Any ideas would be appreciated. If you need more info, I can supply.

here is twitPage.handlebars:

[image]

here is server.js:
[image]

Comment: You should post the code as text, not as images, it's harder for us to help you that way.

Comment: post the actual code not image.you can use of {} sign in editor.